# Distances in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

So my problem is the following:
I have this list of altitudes in a mountain -- test -- and I want to make a function that can return the coordinates (row, column) of the altitude that is to be reached when climbing north.
The climbing starts from any cell besides the cells in row 0, and ends when the cell above has a smaller/equal value than the one below.
the climbing proceeds on a straight line upwards.

Each cell represents an altitude.

---

What i tried is obviously wrong, so if anyone could help me it would be great!
Thank you!

```
test = [
   [206,205,204,190,208],
   [190,194,206,197,203], 
   [196,196,205,201,193],
   [194,199,199,206,205], 
   [192,196,195,201,193], 
   [194,199,200,200,205], 
   [196,196,195,200,193] ]

def climb_north(altitude, start):

    r = start[0]
    c = start[1]
    while (altitudes[r][c]) < (altitudes[?][c]):
       if (altitudes[r][c]) > (altitudes[?][c]):
           break
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I have from what I understood, there are some cases where `None` is returned

```
def climb_north(altitude, start):

    r = start[0]
    c = start[1]
    r_next = r - 1

    while (r_next >= 0):

       if (altitude[r][c]) > (altitude[r_next][c]):
           return (r_next, c)

       r, r_next = r_next, r-1

    return
```

Comment: You almost got it, but the function should return the coordinates of the highest value, not the value above that one. Thanks anyways, because you helped a lot!